# Auto Reply To Email With Private Information

Tags: php, html, asp.net, email, forum

Hi there i have this code which i get and email from a submission forum on my website however i would like to know how i can auto reply to each email with a unique password from a list of pre created passwords i created before hand.

**here is my code:**

```
    <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**php code:**

```
<?php

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='someone@somewhere.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: - Pre-created passwords stored on the webserver is not a good idea imho.

Comment: do you have any other ideas where i can pull the passwords from a list   and send them per request ?

Comment: @SananeLaoan - if you get a request for a password, you can generate one then. Add it to the database and send it in the email. You can add a timestamp to the database, too, so you can track how many have been created today, and add an extra check to make sure that the limit hasn't been reached before you create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

- Pre-created passwords stored on the webserver is not a good idea imho.
- You already have the solution up there, just send another mail with

  mail($receiver,$subject,$message,$header);
- If you still insist on doing this, instead of generating passwords and send them to your customer and eventually yourself, store them in a database.

Edit: The intended behaviour with codes in table myCodeTable, consisting of column id, code and sentFlag, would be something like:

```
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id,code FROM myCodeTable WHERE sentFlag = 0 LIMIT 1");
if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $subject = "Your Code";
  $message = "Your desired message. ".$row['code'];
  $send_pass = mail($customer_mail,$subject,$message);
  if($send_pass){
    mysql_query("UPDATE myCodeTable SET sentFlag=1 WHERE id=".$row['id']);
  }
}
```

Comment: well think of the passwords as a coupon they are already set i just need to be able to distribute these per request

Comment: Then store them in a database with a *sent-flag* column and just send the next unused. For the login just check if the given code is set in the database and is valid (has sent-flag)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table with all the passwords and then fetch one by one and append to your mail.
If you need them to be unique you could add a field which mars whether it has been used or not.

Comment: but i rather suggest you dont pre-create but rather create them on the go.

Comment: well i manually have to create them before hand for my system so is there a way i can distribute  the pre created passwords from a database until the limit is reached ? for instance if the subject is password i want to be able to auto reply instantly with a password fetched from the list if there is no more passwords left it should email stating todays limit has been reached until i load more passwords

Comment: yes it can be done..you could delete or mark them as used every time you use the password. When you run a query like 

Select password from TablePswd where marked=0;

if you get the number of rows fetched as zero you can notify that the daily limit is reached or else send the first password fetched and mark it as used.